# Losing my session variables on post back, but only sometimes

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I'm adding a new process to an existing asp.net website. A vendor is looking to post data to our site and receive catalog data in return. For testing purposes, I created a test page that passes test data to the new page -- that works fine. Session variables appear to persist.

When I test from the vendor's site, the session variable are lost when I do a postback on the page. The data from the vendor arrives fine. Session values appear on the "trace=true" display fine. When I do a post back (in this case, a search button) the app fails due to no @customer parm passed to the SQL server stored proc (missing session variable).

Suggestions are appreciated. This is my first experience as a member of this site so please be kind :)

Comment: To get more visibility of your issue, add tags for the relevant frameworks. It looks like either asp or asp.net maybe?

Comment: Please add more details and/or post some code of the affected areas of your application.

Comment: Is the vendor's site running off multiple web servers ?

Comment: As this site is just for dev and testing, I don't believe it's distributed.